# clojure application - lein uberjar suppress compile time output

Tags: java, shell, clojure, leiningen

While building my clojure application using lein I get compiler output as shown below. I looked at the options for lein and did not see an option to suppress the output. Please let me know if there is an option to suppress output on a successful compilation.

```
clojure_example]$ lein uberjar
Created /home/henninb/projects/howto/src/common/example/clojure_example/uberjar/example-1.0.jar
Created /home/henninb/projects/howto/src/common/example/clojure_example/uberjar/example-1.0-standalone.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is more of a general shell question than Java/Clojure/Leiningen. Try this for redirecting output to the void:

```
lein uberjar >&/dev/null
```

Comment: Completely agree with with you Taylor. Interestingly enough, there are some features in leiningen which suppress some level of logging/output... https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/2a93e282b15c26dd5dc951e1ab692d95e516aba0/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/main.clj#L135 It doesn't help answer OP's question, but is tangentially related to the discussion, so posting here in case folks come looking.